# Efficiently generating discrete random numbers

Tags: r, random, memory-efficient

I want to quickly generate discrete random numbers where I have a known CDF. Essentially, the algorithm is:

1. Construct the CDF vector (an increasing vector starting at 0 and end at 1) `cdf`
2. Generate a uniform(0, 1) random number `u`

   - If `u < cdf[1]` choose 1
   - else if `u < cdf[2]` choose 2
   - else if `u < cdf[3]` choose 3
     *...

**Example**

First generate an cdf:

```
cdf = cumsum(runif(10000, 0, 0.1))
cdf = cdf/max(cdf)
```

Next generate `N` uniform random numbers:

```
N = 1000
u = runif(N)
```

Now sample the value:

```
##With some experimenting this seemed to be very quick
##However, with N = 100000 we run out of memory
##N = 10^6 would be a reasonable maximum to cope with
colSums(sapply(u, ">", cdf))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `cut`:

```
N <- 1e6
u <- runif(N)
system.time(as.numeric(cut(u,cdf)))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.03    0.03    1.07 

head(table(as.numeric(cut(u,cdf))))

  1   2   3   4   5   6 
 51  95 165 172 148  75
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know the probability mass function (which you do, if you know the cumulative distribution function), you can use R's built-in `sample` function, where you can define the probabilities of discrete events with argument `prob`.

```
cdf = cumsum(runif(10000, 0, 0.1))
cdf = cdf/max(cdf)

system.time(sample(size=1e6,x=1:10000,prob=c(cdf[1],diff(cdf)),replace=TRUE))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.02
```

Comment: And it is efficient as " If replace is true, Walker's alias method (Ripley, 1987) is used when there are more than 250 reasonably probable values" time complexity would be O(n)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a finite number of possible values then you can use `findInterval` or `cut` or better `sample` as mentioned by @Hemmo.

However, if you want to generate data from a distribution that that theoretically goes to infinity (like the geometric, negative binomial, Poisson, etc.) then here is an algorithm that will work (this will also work with a finite number of values if wanted):

Start with your vector of uniform values and loop through the distribution values subtracting them from the vector of uniforms, the random value is the iteration where the value goes negative.  This is a easier to see whith an example.  This generates values from a Poisson with mean 5 (replace the `dpois` call with your calculated values) and compares it to using the inverse CDF (which is more efficient in this case where it exists).

```
i <- 0
tmp <- tmp2 <- runif(10000)
randvals <- rep(0, length(tmp) )

while( any(tmp > 0) ) {
    tmp <- tmp - dpois(i, 5)
    randvals <- randvals + (tmp > 0)
    i <- i + 1
}

randvals2 <- qpois( tmp2, 5 )

all.equal(randvals, randvals2)
```

Comment: Good point about distributions with infinite supports, somehow I forgot those.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. However, the algorithm as written would have terrible performance in R. Currently, I use large `i` steps and I think I'll use `cut` to generate the random numbers.